# angular require parent controller without explicitly specifying name

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

The common scenario of requiring a parent controller in a child directive shown here:

the **Client** directive requires the parent **Server** controller

```
  <div server>
    <div client></div>
  </div>



var app = angular.module("app", []);

app.directive("server", function() {
  return {
   controller: function() {
      this.log = function(message) {
        console.log(message);
      };
    }
  };
});

app.directive("client", function() {
  return {
    require: "^server",
    link: function($scope, $elem, $attrs, serverCtrl) {
      serverCtrl.log("Hello, this is the client!");
    }
  };
});
```

What if I have a third directive directive called **MegaServer**

```
app.directive("MegaServer", function() {
  return {
   controller: function() {
      this.log = function(message) {
        console.log(message);
      };
    }
  };
});
```

**MegaServer** can also be a parent to "Client".

```
  <div server>
    <div client></div>
  </div>
  <div mega-server>
    <div client></div>
  </div>
```

How do I define my **Client** directive to require the parent controller if it can be of type either **Server** or **MegaServer**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have the other server publish its `this` on its `$scope`. Then have the `client` directive use either the optionally required `serverCtrl` or the `$scope.serverCtrl`.

```
angular.module("app").directive("otherServer", function() {
  return {
   controller: function($scope) {
      $scope.serverCtrl = this;       
      this.log = function(message) {
        console.log("otherServer: ", message);
      };
    }
  };
});

angular.module("app").directive("client", function() {
  return {
    require: "^?server",
    link: function(scope, elem, attrs, serverCtrl) {
      var ctrl = serverCtrl || scope.serverCtrl;
      if (ctrl) {  
         ctrl.log("Hello, from a client");
         ctrl.log("My scope.$id is " + scope.$id);
      };
    }
  };
});
```

Try it out [on JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ut0fsfb1/).